# Simplemente, cómo hago que funcione ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estoy haciendo un proyectillo y no me funciona nada de nada, y no sé qué hacer... Tengo 3 formularios en una página para gestionar, dos de ellos hacen una consulta en la BD (uno por un input y el otro por un select), el otro hace un insert, y abajo un div donde muestra el resultado de la búsqueda que haya hecho el form de arriba. Soy bastante nuevo en esto de ajax y jquery y no sé cómo encontrar los fallos, por más que pruebo cosas.

Aquí tengo todo subido:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FREeCxD4Wf-LPcFo7CaP5020KYmoRi0K

Gracias de antemano =)

mostrardatos.php, aquí tengo los formularios y el div donde deben aparecer los datos

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <!--formulario para insertar,     formulario para buscar y div para mostrar datos-->
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stilo.css" />
      <title>Registro cesiones</title>
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="title" content="Registro de cesiones de Striker Manager">
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="ajax.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>Consulta (esto va por ajax) SON DOS FORMS DISTINTOS</p>
      <form name="frmBuscarnick" method="POST">
         <label for="nick">Buscar por nombre de manager</label>
         <input type="text" name="nick" id="nick" required>
         <input type="submit" value="Enviar" onclick="Cargarnick();">
      </form>
      <br>
      <form name="frmBuscarpos" method="POST">
         <label for="posicion">Buscar por posición</label>
         <select id="posicion" name="posicion">
            <option value="0" selected>Selecciona</option>
            <option value="po">PO</option>
            <option value="lx">LX</option>
            <option value="dfx">DFX</option>
            <option value="mdf">MDF</option>
            <option value="mx">MX</option>
            <option value="mcx">MCX</option>
            <option value="mo">MO</option>
            <option value="ex">EX</option>
            <option value="dlx">DLX</option>
         </select>
         <input type="submit" value="Enviar" onclick="Cargarpos();">
      </form>
      <br><br>
      <p>Insertar (esto va por ajax)</p>
      <form name="frmInsertar" method="POST">
         <div>
            <label for="txtNick">Nick: </label>
            <input type="text" name="txtNick" id="nick" required>
         </div>
         <div>
            <label for="posicion">Posición</label>
            <select id="posicion" name="posicion">
               <option value="0" selected>Selecciona</option>
               <option value="po">PO</option>
               <option value="lx">LX</option>
               <option value="dfx">DFX</option>
               <option value="mdf">MDF</option>
               <option value="mx">MX</option>
               <option value="mcx">MCX</option>
               <option value="mo">MO</option>
               <option value="ex">EX</option>
               <option value="dlx">DLX</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <input type="submit" value="Enviar" onclick="Insertar();">
      </form>
      <h1>Listado</h1>
      <h1>Aquí se muestra la lista del formulario de arriba</h1>
      <div class="caja" id="caja">
   </body>
</html>
```

---

ajax.js

```
window.onload = function() {
    Cargar();
}

function Insertar() {
    var nick = $("#nick").val();
    var posicion = $("#posicion").prop('selectedIndex');
    // $("#respuesta").html("Por favor espera un momento");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'html',
        url: "insertar.php",
        data: "nick=" + nick + "&posicion=" + posicion,
        success: function(resp) {
            // $('#respuesta').html(resp);
            Limpiar();
            Cargar();
        }
    });
}

function Cargarnick() {
    $('#caja').load('consultanick.php');
}

function Cargarpos() {
    $('#caja').load('consultapos.php');
}

function Limpiar() {
    $("#nick").val("");
    //limpio el select a su opción por defecto
    $("posicion").change(function() {
        $("posicion").not(this).prop('selectedIndex', 0);
        /*$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#sel").val("0");
});*/
    });
}
```

---

insertar.php

```
$nick = $_POST["nick"];
$posicion = $_POST["posicion"];

$comprobar_nick=mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM manager WHERE nick='$nick' ");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($comprobar_nick) >0 || $posicion=="0"){
    echo '<script> alert("Ese nick ya existe, o no has introducido la posición");
     </script>';
      //echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=modificar.php">';
    exit;
}else{

    $sql = "INSERT INTO manager(nick, posicion) VALUES('" .$nick. "','" .$posicion. "')";
    $insertar=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
    if(!$insertar){
        echo '<script> alert("Ha ocurrido un problema");
     </script>';
    }else{
        echo '<script> alert("Registro añadido");
     </script>';
    }

    }
    //echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=modificar.php">';
 mysqli_close($conexion); 
 ?>
```

Download Form

---

consultarnick.php

```
<?php
require("conexion.php");
$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM manager where nick='$nick'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($consulta) > 0) {
    echo " <table>  <tr> <th>id</th> <th>nick</th> <th>posicion</th> </tr>  </table> ";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['idmanager'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['nick'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['posicion'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
else 
{ 
    echo " <p>No hay nada</p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Trate de poner el código en la pregunta. Es más fácil para nosotros si vemos el código

Comment: Lo he pegado pero no se ve bien porque se come párrafos y código php

Comment: Qué problema específicamente está teniendo?

Answer (score 0):

He de notar que el codigo que aquí pusiste es algo diferente al que esta en los archivos que compratiste de tu proyecto, el caso es que me tome la libertar de modificar este archivo, espero te pueda servir como referencia para trabajar con el resto.

consultarnick.php

```
    <?php
    require("conexion.php");
    $sql="SELECT * FROM manager";
    $result=$conexion->query($sql);
    if (!$result) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conexion));
        exit();
    }else{echo " <table> <thead> <tr> <th>id</th> <th>nick</th> <th>posicion</th> </tr> </thead> </table> ";
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<tr>"; 
            echo "<td>".$row['idmanager']."</td>"; echo "<td>".$row['nick']."</td>"; echo "<td>".$row['posicion']."</td>"; 
            echo "</tr>"; 
        }   
    } 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

No te va a funcionar nunca ya que no tienes la función **Cargar()** en ningún sitio. Aunque la llamas cuando se termina de cargar el documento HTML.

```
window.onload = function() {
    Cargar();
}
```